# Prevent JQuery injected script running before injected html from same file in DOM after AJAX call

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I seem to have encountered a race condition when running scripts injected into my webpage over ajax. For example I have a file that looks like this:

```
<div id='test_id'>I'm a div</div>
<script>$(function(){alert('Do something to #test_id')});</script>
```

I am loading that file using JQuery's post method and attaching it to a JQueryUI dialog. Like so:

```
var $dialog = $("<div id='div_dialog'></div>")
    .dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        title: 'NA',
        modal: true,
        width: '50%',
        buttons: {some button object},
    });
$dialog.dialog('open');

$.post(
    [url to get page], 
    {}, 
    function(data) {
        $('#div_dialog').html('<div id="messages"></div>' + data);
    });
```

The problem is that when the alert pops up, the dialog is showing on the page as expected, but it has no html in it. Then when I click away the alert the html shows as expected.

What I expect to happen, is that the html is attached, and then the script is run. This is not the case. I've tried `$(document).ready()` and `$(window).load()` as well as `$(document).ajaxComplete()` and `$(document).ajaxSuccess()` without any luck. It DOES work if I put it in a setTimeout with some millisecond delay. But thats.... wrong.

I should also mention that what I am hoping for is a solution that does not require me to change the AJAX request as I wont always have access to that file - others will be importing my created files over ajax using the pattern I specified.

Comment: If you don't want the dialog to show until the html is added, put the `dialog('open')` logic **inside** your post callback that is putting the html on it

Comment: This still does not work. The HTML is still not attached, the alert runs even though the dialog is not showing on the screen and the DOM elements are not available.

Comment: Wait, are you expecting the script in the html to not execute until you show it?

Comment: could put the script in separate file and use `$.getScript()` after the html is inserted....or wrap the script in a setTimeout to give time for html to be rendered

Comment: Sorry @Taplar, wasn't clear. No, I am expecting the script to run after the DOM elements are inserted - regardless of whether or not the dialog shows. I think I may have found another issue though and thats the div I was attempting to run the script on is potentially replaced is another div of equal content after the div loads thanks to some scripts on the ajax callers page. My issue may not be what I thought it was.

Comment: Well, the script will run as soon as you add it to the DOM regardless of if you want it to or not.  The primary way of "delaying" it would be to change the script to have what you want to do in a function, and after the modal is shown to call that function.